# Android: starting an activity in another app with only default action/category

Tags: android, html, cordova, android-intent

I've read the docs but there's still one thing that I'm not quite sure of...

Is it possible to start an Activity in another app that only has the following intent-filters set up?:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

(I'm actually trying to start this activity using the webintent cordova plugin, but hav not had much success)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to start this activity, the only thing you need is the name com.your_domain.YourLaunchActivity.

Comment: more here http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use the this Cordova plug-in to start an app:

https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp